# Converting Numbers from French Locale to English Locale JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have  a list of number like "123,459","561,79" from france region and I want to convert it into our normal US english numbering system. How can I do it in JS using locale?

```
function eArabic(x){
 return x.toLocaleString('en-US',{ minimumFractionDigits:2, 
     maximumFractionDigits:2 });
}

Input  : "123,345"
Output : "123,345"
Expected Output : 123.345
```

This doesn't looks good. Do you have any suggestion for this problem? I do not want to replace comma with '.' in order to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you provide an example of expected input and output?

Comment: I know using a library just for this issue might be redundant but I suggest you take a look at [AutoNumeric.js](http://autonumeric.org). You might wanna use it after

Comment: Presumably your expected output would be a string as well? Or are you really looking for a float?

Answer (score 0):

You’re passing in a string, not a Number object (which is what `toLocaleString` requires to produce a formatted number). Do you have the original number available?

If you don’t, then your best bet (assuming a standardised format for the original number strings) would be to convert them into normal numbers then reformat them. Assuming that your numbers are going to be formatted according to French standards (`,` as a decimal separator) then you could use a simple string replacement before creating your number object:

```
var frenchNumberString = '123,456';
var numberObject = new Number(frenchNumberString.replace(',', '.'));
```

Then pass `numberObject` into your formatting code.

Comment: what we really need is a fromLocaleString function